# Opacity of content within a container

Tags: html, css, opacity

I have a container with the `background-color` set with CSS. In this container there are 4 other `div`s. I want to display the container with `0.5` opacity. However, when I do that, the content of the container also displays at `0.5` opacity. Is there any way I can display the container content at full opacity?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

CSS 3 introduces [rgba colours](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/#rgba-color). You can combine them with [translucent PNG](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/#creating-the-image) background images for [backwards compatibility](http://dorward.me.uk/www/css/alpha-colour/).

```
#alpha {
    background: url(blue_0.5_pixel.png);
    background: rgba(0%, 0%, 100%, 0.5);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything: `opacity: 0.5;`
Only the background: `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`
Some browsers may not support RGBA though, so make sure you take a look at that.

Answer (score 1):

Use the RGBA background color feature.

```
.containerclass { background-color: rgba(255, 255, 128, .5); }
```

Comment: See this for adding support for IE8 and below (ugly hack; you have been warned!): http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/

Answer (score 0):

For browsers that support CSS3, you can use a semi-transparent color. You can also use a semi-transparent PNG for background, but that's not supported in IE6 (if that is a problem).

Otherwise it's not possible to have a 0.5 opacity on the container without it's children inheriting it. You would have to place two elements on top of each other using absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution:

> [Reducing the opacity on a div without reducing the opacity of the contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2927960/reducing-the-opacity-on-a-div-without-reducing-the-opacity-of-the-contents)